# Wifi crashes sometimes after PC wakeup (MSI GS60 2QE)

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, sleep, wifi-driver

When my computer (MSI GS60 2QE) is in sleep, when it resumes from sleep, wifi crashes half the time (the network card isn't detected anymore and I have to put my computer in sleep again to ensure it works again). I've installed Killer Network driver and Intel PROSet/Wireless, there are no other drivers I believe. If you want more infos ask me! So have you an idea how I can solve my problem? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" option of your wireless network adapter and enable "Allow this device to wake the computer". Please follow the below steps.

Press Windows key+r > type 'ncpa.cpl' and press enter > right click on your wireless network adapter > Properties > click on 'Configure' > go to Power Management tab and un-check and check the above options.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't check "Allow this device to wake the computer", the option is disabled. I've uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" but it will not reduce the lifetime of my battery?

Comment: My computer was in sleep mode about 1h30 and I've lost 35-40% of my battery, so your solution isn't very good... :/ Any other idea?